# Use variable from AWSCLI in azure pipelines for script

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, aws-cli, azure-pipelines-yaml

I have a build process where I need to use a token, received through the AWSCLI. So far I have connected aws to my azure pipelines but I am having trouble setting up my yaml.
I want to fetch the relevant token to use it later as a variable in my script.

As you can see in my yaml I am running a powershell script with codeartifact and I am saving the value to my **myOutputVar**. The powershell script does not throw an error.
However, later when I run the building script that variable is not present resulting in **ECHO is off.**

How can I ensure the value received in the task can be used later in the script/build part?

```
trigger:
- azure-pipelines

pool:
  vmImage: windows-latest

steps:
- task: NodeTool@0
  inputs:
    versionSpec: '10.x'
  displayName: 'Install Node.js'
- task: AWSPowerShellModuleScript@1
  inputs:
    awsCredentials: 'AWS Connection'
    regionName: 'eu-central-1'
    scriptType: 'inline'
    inlineScript: '##vso[task.setvariable variable=myOutputVar;]aws codeartifact get-authorization-token --domain somedomain  --domain-owner 444.... --query authorizationToken --output text; '
- script: |
    echo %myOutputVar%
    npm ci
    npm run build
  displayName: 'npm install and build'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your inline script can be multiple lines, and since this is PowerShell you can do something like:

```
inlineScript: |
   $authToken = aws codeartifact get-authorization-token `
                    --domain somedomain `
                    --domain-owner 444.... `
                    --query authorizationToken `
                    --output text

   Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=myOutputVar;]$authToken"
```

Comment: Thx for the solid explanation. This is how it works.